Quick Switch View with Pen
I'm struggling to find a way to switch the view while using a pen, with the "Emulate 3 Button Mouse" checked.
With the mouse the "quick switch view" works when pressing the Alt and then dragging (quickly) in the direction desired.
How to use this feature with a digital pen?
Thank you in advance!
